# Python 3.3 - Connect with Oracle database

Tags: python, oracle, python-3.3

Is there a module for python 3.3 to connect with Oracle Databases? Which is the easiest to use? Something like the mysql module, only works with Oracle.

Preferably version 10g, but 11g will do just fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**There is:** `cx_Oracle`

```
# Install --> You should have oracle installed otherwise exception will be raised

pip install cx_Oracle

import cx_Oracle

con = cx_Oracle.connect('pythonhol/welcome@127.0.0.1/orcl')
print con.version

con.close()
```

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Python

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/python-091105.html

Comment: Do I really need the Oracle client to have this working? Isn't as simple as a direct JDBC connection? Ty.

Answer (score 2):

if you're using python3

```
pip3 install cx_Oracle
```

How to connet oracle and get oracle time:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#coding=utf8


# import module
import cx_Oracle 

con = cx_Oracle.connect('username/password@databasename')

# create cursor
cursor = con.cursor()

# execute sql
cursor.execute('select sysdate from dual')

# fetch one data, or fetchall()
data = cursor.fetchone()

print('Database time:%s' % data)

# close cursor and oracle
cursor.close()
con.close()
```